# Magento 1.9 Combine external javascript files

Tags: javascript, performance, google-api

I run performance test through Pindom tools, I got a result saying I need to combine external JavaScript files. I know Magento has a feature to combine all local JavaScript files into one file. But how to combine the external ones?

[image]

It's about these files

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/common.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/controls.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/geocoder.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/infowindow.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/map.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/marker.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/onion.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/12/util.js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Authent ... htAKU6FT4fAM4&callback=_xdc_._7duho1&token=81040
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Geocode ... htAKU6FT4fAM4&callback=_xdc_._ja54gz&token=80119
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Viewpor ... 0000&7b0&8e0&callback=_xdc_._vi8nk4&token=113027
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/Viewpor ... 00000&7b0&8e0&callback=_xdc_._xp4b9k&token=35277
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAA1E2Rcxs8vYcJArt1GKhtAKU6FT4fAM4
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3 ... !4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._7rk4vn&token=43082
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3 ... !4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._7z4nki&token=24193
```

Comment: Are you sure it is referring to those files? External javascript normally means external to the html file as opposed to written in the html (inline)

Comment: @jscar I think you are right about the definition. The pingdom tools did also show a list of my own javascripts, that should be combined into fewer. Those I can do by using Magentos standard merge javascript function. It's just these javasripts from google I'm not sure how to deal with.

Comment: @venkatesh is correct - you can't :(

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to control the things which is external to your site. We can only combine the css and js files which is served from server.